# Texts under li's get mess up when text is lengthy

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using [WooCommerce Plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) for WordPress to make an `ecommerce store`. But my problem is that some of items have title more than 50-60 characters . By this the layout for the product goes mess up. Here I am attaching the screen shot for the layout. Kindly suggest me what should I do here? Live site you can get [here](http://modulesoft.info/projects/gamesite/).

[image]

**Update**

Broken screen image is here[image]

Comment: I cannot spot what is wrong. Could you please specify which frame is messed up and how?

Comment: Do you mean the facebook plugin? Thats the only thing i can see that is messed up. Further your lay out messes up once you use a break in it, with the world of secrets. Because of the break your lay out gets stretched. THe others dont follow, which means your css needs to be adjusted to the same height

Comment: No I want to tell you all the products title. Suppose when there will be 50-60 character length title will be there then the layout is messing up.You can enter text with firebug or developer tools then you can see.

Comment: or you can provide a broken screenshot for starters :) ps: some titles are way wrong ("Bettle field", "Mediaval"), maybe you want correct them too (just a quick debug on the fly since i looked at your page)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I have uploaded the broken screen image. Kindly suggest me how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have about 3 options.

1. do nothing and live with it
2. constraint the `li` or the `h3` height and have it scroll/hide the overflow.
3. cut down the titles

Number 2 would be to add this to the css :

```
div#content ul.products li.product {height:300px; overflow:auto;}
```

or it could also be to add this instead :

```
div#content ul.products li.product h3 {height:1em;overflow:hidden}
```

Number 3 is about simply not having long title...
when you write the game title, look if the string length is greater than *your limit*, if so, only print a substr and append "...".

There's one other solution I can think of, but it's a bit more complicated. Take the game title length and scale down your text size accordingly, up to a certain threshold.